# Learning about determinantal varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, determinants, projective-varieties

In my research  I recently stumbled upon a problem which involves trying to identify whether a given projective variety is determinantal or, even stronger, determinantal of a particular form. For example, I am interested in questions like 'can $X$ be written as a determinantal hypersurface, i.e. the zero-set of the polynomial $$\det\sum_{i=0}^n x_iA_i, $$ where the matrices $A_i$ are of rank $k$ at most'.

To do that I would like to learn as much as possible about specific properties of determinantal varieties. What are the good references for this topic? I have read the relevant chapters of Harris' 'Algebraic Geometry: A First Course', but couldn't find more in-depth, but sufficiently general, resources. The papers I have found tend to work with some very specific cases.

So what are, in your opinion, the things an algebraic geometer needs to know about determinantal varieties? I am particularly interested in their automorphism groups (and how to work out the automorphism group of a projective variety in general) and linear sections. I think I have found that linear sections of a generic determinantal hypersurface are generally non-isomorphic (except possibly some low-dimensional cases), and this seems like a very basic fact, but I haven't found it anywhere on the web and would really love some geometric intuition for why this is the case.

Comment: Beauville, Arnaud. Determinantal hypersurfaces. Dedicated to William Fulton on the occasion of his 60th birthday. Michigan Math. J. 48 (2000), 39--64.

Comment: @Sasha That's a beautiful paper for sure, forgot to mention it. But it only deals with determinantal curves and surfaces, and I am more interested in varieties of higher dimension.

Comment: Chapter II of "Geometry of Algebraic Curves", Vol. 1, by Arbarello, Cornalba, Griffiths, and Harris. Springer (1985).

Comment: @F Zaldivar Thanks a lot! That was a very illuminating read.